# I don't need the run() method in a Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask application setup on my linode with a directory structure like so:

```
|--------flask-test
|----------------app
|-----------------------static
|-----------------------templates
|-----------------------venv
|-----------------------__init__.py
|-----------------------main.py
```

my `__init__.py` is:

```
# __init__.py
from flask import Flask
from main import main
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(main)
app.run()
```

and `main.py` like so:

```
# main.py
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main',__name__)
@main.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@main.route("/england/")
def england():
    return "Hello England!"
```

If I run the app locally there are no issues. If I go to my server address in the web browser I get an internal server error. However if I remove the line: `app.run` from `__init__.py` it works fine. Why is this? Why do I not need the run method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The reason is that Apache or NGINX or some other web server loads your app directly on the server but `app.run()` runs flask's internal web-server so you can test your app.

EDIT:
Since someone came by and upvoted this very old answer (thanks!) I will point out that there is no reason to include this convention. Flask includes a run command for testing.

Instead of the old way:

```
python yourapp.py
```

you now do:

```
flask --app yourapp run
```

Or if you name the main controller of your app "app.py" you can commit the `--app` flag.

Answer (score 5):

It is a bit odd to have `app.run()` inside of the `__init__.py` file, normally it would be in a separate application script you run, where it would be written as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This way `app.run()` is only called when that script is executed as the application.

This is necessary because you do not want `app.run()` called when hosting under a WSGI server such as mod_wsgi or gunicorn. When using such WSGI servers, even if reusing the same script file as holder of the WSGI application entrypoint, `__name__` wouldn't be set to `__main__` but the basename of the script file. This ensures that `app.run()` isn't called where it is the separate WSGI server which is running the web server component.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I moved it to a separate `run.py` script and added it to `.gitignore` to keep it off my linode server.

Comment: Using 'flask run' also starts the development server so why do we need app.run() please?

Comment: The post is from 3 years ago. Use of `flask run` is a newer preferred method.

Comment: Thank you for this - yes I agree this causes confusion